# Groovy can't find a method matching my arguments

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm befuddled with a Groovy method resolution problem.

I'm working in the Groovy code for a Gradle custom plugin.

I have the following code in a method of my Task class:

```
    if (inspectDependencies) {
        project.configurations[yangFilesConfiguration].files.each { File file ->
            println file
            println "filetype:${file.getClass().getName()} excludeFilesType:${excludeFiles.getClass().getName()}"
            this.getYangFilesFromZip(file, excludeFiles).each { File yangFile
                println yangFile
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have a method definition later in the same Task class:

```
    private Collection<File> getYangFilesFromZip(File file, Collection<String> excludeFiles) {
    ....
```

When I run this code, I see the following:

```
filetype:java.io.File excludeFilesType:java.util.ArrayList
...
Could not find method getYangFilesFromZip() for arguments [C:\Users\dk068x\workspace2\YangUsingProject\libs\config-api-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, [target.yang]] on task ':yangGenerate'.
```

As you can see, the actual types of the parameters are compatible with the formal parameters of the method.  What could be going wrong here?

**Update**:

I added the following line between the first println and the call to "getYangFilesFromZip":

```
print "this[$this] owner[$owner] delegate[$delegate]"
```

When I run it, it prints:

```
this[task ':yangGenerate'] owner[task ':yangGenerate'] delegate[task ':yangGenerate']
```

I also tried the variations in the call itself, with "getYangFilesFromZip", "this.getYangFilesFromZip", and "owner.getYangFilesFromZip".  I even tried declaring a "YangGenerate" variable before the closure and assigning it from "this" and referencing that instead of the other variations.  No change.

**Update**:

Here's a minimal test case that gets the same error:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;

class ResolutionProblem {
    static main(args) {
        Collection<String>  list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
        if (args.length > 0) {
            File    file = new File(".")
            list.each {
                owner.getYangFilesFromZip(file, list)
            }
        }
    }

    private Collection<File> getYangFilesFromZip(File file, Collection<String> excludeFiles) {
    }
}
```

Comment: At the first sight it's the *this, owner, delegate*, see here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures. I guess that `this` that prepends the method call isn't equal to task's `this`. It could be easily checked.

Comment: Ok, good idea, but it doesn't pan out here.  I updated with more information.

Comment: Any full, runnable example to reproduce?

Comment: Ok, looks like the standalone test case I added in the next update demonstrates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;

class ResolutionProblem {
    static main(args) {
        Collection<String> list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
        File file = new File(".")
        list.each {
           new ResolutionProblem().getYangFilesFromZip(file, list)
        }
    }

    public Collection<File> getYangFilesFromZip(File file, Collection<String> excludeFiles) {
        println(file)
        println(excludeFiles)
    }
}
```

It's impossible to invoke *private* method `getYangFilesFromZip` from **static** block without even creating an object that has this class declared. You should either create the object or change method signature to be *static*.

Comment: Forgetting to instantiate the object was a dumb error just made in the standalone test. I should have made sure the test didn't fail when I commented out the suspect call, which I neglected to do. What actually fixed the problem was changing the access level of "getYangFilesFromZip" to non-private (leaving it package-protected works). I was used to Java faking it with "synthetic accessors" for anonymous inner classes, so it didn't occur to me this was a problem.

Comment: Ok, understood ;) So please prepare an example that really reproduces the problem. If it requires to provide a gradle example, please provide it.

Comment: Hmph. I'm having more trouble generating the test case than I thought. Groovy has no trouble calling a private method from within the closure. Removing the access spec on the real method fixed my original problem, but I still can't recreate it with the test case.